# How do I pass a conditional expression as a parameter in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

For example this what I am trying to do,

```
def method_a(condition, params={}, &block)
   if condition
      method_b(params, &block)
   else
      yield
   end
end
```

and I am trying to call the method like this,

```
method_a(#{@date > Date.today}, {:param1 => 'value1', :param2 => 'value2'}) do

end
```

The result is the condition is always evaluated to true. How do I make it work?

Comment: Why are you passing the condition in the first place? Why not put the "if" in the calling code?

Comment: Indeed. There's a smell to that code.

Comment: I am actually calling it from rails view. The method is in a helper. Wrapping the call to method_b in a if block in the view would not work since we have block that follows it with an end tag.

Answer (score 4):

Can't you just pass `condition` as the result of a conditional evaluation?

```
method_a(@date > Date.today, {:param1 => 'value1', :param2 => 'value2'}) do
    puts "Do stuff"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the sensible way to do this would be using a Proc or lambda:

```
def method_a(condition, params={}, &block)
   if condition.call
      method_b(params, &block)
   else
      yield
   end
end

method_a(lambda { @date > Date.today }, { :param1 => 'value1', :param2 => 'value2' }) do
  # ...
end
```

A lambda is not evaluated until you call `call` on it.

Comment: This is unnecessary. The condition will have to be evaluated *anyway*, it doesn't make sense to evaluate it lazily. A block/proc/lambda is only needed for the parts that you *do not* want to evaluate *depending* on the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you didn't have that comment there in the middle of the line, it would pretty much just work:

```
method_a(@date > Date.today, {:param1 => 'value1', :param2 => 'value2'}) do; end
```

By the way: if the very last argument to a method is a hash, you can leave off the curly braces, which makes it read almost like Python-style keyword arguments:

```
method_a(@date > Date.today, :param1 => 'value1', :param2 => 'value2') do; end
```

If you use Ruby 1.9, and you have a hash where the keys are symbols, you can use the new alternative hash syntax:

```
method_a(@date > Date.today, {param1: 'value1', param2: 'value2'}) do; end
```

Combining the two *really* looks like keyword arguments:

```
method_a(@date > Date.today, param1: 'value1', param2: 'value2') do; end
```

In your `method_a`, you could greatly improve the readability by using a guard clause instead of the big honking `if` expression:

```
def method_a(condition, params={}, &block)
  return method_b(params, &block) if condition
  yield
end
```

Or the other way around, whichever you think reads better:

```
def method_a(condition, params={}, &block)
  return yield unless condition
  method_b(params, &block)
end
```

However, this is a giant code smell. A method should *always* do one thing, and one thing only. *Every* method which takes a boolean argument violates this rule, because it pretty much by definition does *two* things: one thing if the condition is true and a different thing if the condition is false.

In your original code, this is blatantly obvious, because you have the giant `if` expression surrounding the entire method and the code in the two branches is *completely* different. It is even more obvious than that, because the `else` branch not only has completely different code than the `then` branch, it also completely ignores the arguments that are passed into the method! So, not only does the method behave differently depending on the condition, it even has a different *signature*!

What you really want to do, is split the method into two methods. The user of `method_a` needs to know *anyway* what the different behavior between the two cases is, and he has to supply the conditional himself. Instead, he could just call the right method in the first place. So, I would split `method_a` into two:

```
def method_one(params={}, &block)
  method_b(params, &block)
end

def method_two
  yield
end
```

And the client can decide which one to call:

```
if @date > Date.today then
  method_two(param1: 'value1', param2: 'value2')
else
  method_one do
    # something
  end
end
```

But, if you look closely at `method_one`, you will see that all it does is just forwarding its arguments unmodified to `method_b`. So, we can just get rid of `method_one` altogether, and have the client call `method_b` directly.

The same goes for `method_two`: all it does is call the block. The client could have just as well run the code in the first place.

So, now our library code looks like this:

```
# there is no spoon
```

That's right! There is no library code left! (Except for `method_b` which is not part of your question.)

And the client code looks like this:

```
if @date > Date.today then
  method_b(param1: 'value1', param2: 'value2')
else
  # something
end
```

A very good example of a method that violates this rule, is `Module#instance_methods` in the Ruby core library. It tells you all the instance methods defined in a particular module and class and it takes a boolean argument which decides whether or not this list will include the methods inherited from superclasses. *Noone* can *ever* remember whether to pass `false` or `true`. *Noone*. Jim Weirich uses this example in his talks about good design and he usually asks the audience which is the inherited case and which is the immediate case. Usually, a high percentage get it wrong. Sometimes, the percentage is *worse than just flipping a coin*!

If you look at [the documentation](http://Ruby-Doc.Org/ruby-1.9/classes/Module.html#M000919), it is utterly confusing. I can *never* remember which way around the conditional goes, I *always* have to look it up in the documentation. Which isn't really that helpful, because the *official documentation*, which is part of the *actual* sourcecode of YARV and MRI, *has it the wrong way round, too*!

Comment: Actually I am trying to implement conditional cache in rails. That is I want to cache a fragment if certain condition is met. That's all. My decorator method wraps the Rails cache call with a the condition and I have it in the helper. Hope this gives you the background.